# Giffler Thompson Algorithm for decoding individuals of a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: java, beginner, genetic-algorithm

First of all: Hi, my name is Henrik and I am a mechanical engineer, who loves to code in his free time.
To get better in programming I wrote a genetic algorithm compined with a list planning algorithm (giffler thompsoon algorithm) to solve the fjssp (i have encountered this problem in my master thesis 2 years ago).

Although i would like to have help / reviews about the whole program, i think the biggest potential for improvement is in the class "Individuum". Especially the methods "calculateStartingTimeMatrix"  and "decodierung" (decoding) seem to me somehow cumbersome, inefficient and confusing (the latter is certainly also due to the length of the methods).

To the programm:
After reading a production process out of an excel file and creating a population with random individuals i create permissible productionsplans for each individual ("Individuum"). To be able to do that i use the giffler thompson algorithm to decode the individuals. This happens in the "decodierung" method. For the giffler thompson algorithm i need to calculate the starting times at the beginning and every time i add a operation to the production schedule. This happens in the calculateStartingTimeMatrix methode.

```
package planningalgorithm;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Individuum {
    int number;
    int birthGeneration;
    int nOp;
    int nMa;

    int[] indiAllocation;                   // Allocation of this Individual
    int[] indiSequence;                     // Sequenz of this Individual
    int[][] predecessorWorkingTimes;        // Do i need this?
    int[][] startingTimeMatrix;             // Do i need this?
    int[] timesProduction;
    float timeFitness;
    int susRank;
    int tournamentWins;

    List<Machine> indiMachines;                 // Machines of this Individual
    List<Operationen> indiProcess;              // Process of this Individual

    int[] arrayA;
    int[] arrayB;
    int operationDash;
    int operationDashDash;
    int operationStar;


    //Konstruktor
    Individuum(int num, int startgen, int nOp, int nMa){
        number=num;
        this.nOp = nOp;
        this.nMa = nMa;
        birthGeneration=startgen;

        indiAllocation = new int[nOp];
        indiSequence = new int[nOp];
        predecessorWorkingTimes = new int[nOp][nOp];
        startingTimeMatrix = new int[nOp][nOp+1];
        timesProduction = new int[nOp];

        // Liste der Maschinen erstellen
        indiMachines = new ArrayList<>(nMa);
        for (int i=0;i<nMa;i++) {
            Machine newMachine = new Machine(i,0);
            indiMachines .add(newMachine);
        }

        // Liste der Prozesse erstellen
        indiProcess = new ArrayList<>(nOp);
        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++) {
            Operationen newOperation = new Operationen(nOp,nMa);
            indiProcess.add(newOperation);
        }

        arrayA = new int[nOp];
        arrayB = new int[nOp];
    }


    // Zufallszahl 
    private double randomNumber(){
        double ranNum;
        Random zufallszahl = new Random();
        ranNum = zufallszahl.nextDouble();
        return ranNum;
    }

    private double round(double value, int decimalPoints) {
        double d = Math.pow(10, decimalPoints);
        return Math.round(value * d) / d;
     }

    private int max(int[] fooArr) {
        int maximum = -100;
        for (int i=0;i<fooArr.length;i++) {
            if (fooArr[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = fooArr[i];
            }
        }
        return maximum;
    }

    public void copyArr (int[] arr, int[] dest){
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            dest[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    public int[] copyArraySection (int[] originArr, int startPointerArr, int[] destArr, int startPointerDest, int lenghtCopy){
        for (int i=0;i<lenghtCopy;i++){
            destArr[startPointerDest+i] = originArr[startPointerArr+i];
        }
        return destArr;
    }    

    public int[] addOneToArray (int[] arr, int what){
        // Case 1: Array is empty
        if (arr == null){
            int[] newArr = new int[1];
            newArr[0] = what;
            return newArr;
        }
        // Case 2: Array isnt empty
        else {
            int[] newArr = new int[arr.length + 1];
            for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                newArr[i] = arr[i];
            }
            newArr[arr.length] = what;
            return newArr;
        }
    }

    public int[] oneValue(int[] barArr, int value){
        int[] oneValueArr = new int[barArr.length];
        for (int i=0;i<barArr.length;i++){
            oneValueArr[i] = value;
        }
        return oneValueArr;
    }
 
    public int[] changeValue (int[] arrArr, int oldValue, int newValue){
        int[] newArrArr = new int[arrArr.length];
        for (int i=0;i<arrArr.length;i++){
            if (arrArr[i] == oldValue){
                arrArr[i] = newValue;
            }
        }
        return newArrArr;
    }

    public int count (int[] countArr, int value){
        int countDoku = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<countArr.length;i++){
            if (countArr[i]==value){
                countDoku++;
            }
        }
        return countDoku;
    }

    public int[][] copyMatrix (int[][] arr) {
        int[][] copy = new int[arr.length][arr[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                copy[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }


    void calculateStartingTimeMatrix(){
         //Reset startingTimeMatrix except the last column nOp which includes the occupation times
         for (int r=0;r<nOp;r++){
            for (int c=0;c<nOp;c++){
                startingTimeMatrix[r][c] = 0;
            }
        }

        // Reset the status in every operation
        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++){
            indiProcess.get(i).operationDone = false;
            indiProcess.get(i).operationNotReady = true;
            indiProcess.get(i).operationReadyToStart = false;
        }

        // Reset the remainingPredessors
        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++){
             copyArr(indiProcess.get(i).predecessor,indiProcess.get(i).remainingPredecessors);
        }

        // Update StartingTimeMatrix with Operation, that are already planned
        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++){
            if (arrayA[i] == -1){
                indiProcess.get(i).operationDone = true;
                indiProcess.get(i).operationNotReady = false;
                indiProcess.get(i).operationReadyToStart = false;
                for (int z2=0;z2<nOp;z2++){
                    if (indiProcess.get(z2).predecessor[i] == 1){
                        startingTimeMatrix[z2][i] = indiProcess.get(i).timeEnd;
                        indiProcess.get(z2).remainingPredecessors[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++){
            if (arrayA[i] == 1){
                indiProcess.get(i).operationDone = false;
                indiProcess.get(i).operationNotReady = false;
                indiProcess.get(i).operationReadyToStart = true;
            }
        }

    
        int operationsDone = 0;
        while (operationsDone < nOp){

            
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                int foundOp = 0;

                // Search for starting Operation
                if (indiProcess.get(z).operationReadyToStart == true){
                    foundOp = z;
                    for (int z2=0;z2<nOp;z2++){
                        if (indiProcess.get(z2).predecessor[foundOp] == 1){
                            startingTimeMatrix[z2][foundOp] = max(startingTimeMatrix[foundOp]) + predecessorWorkingTimes[z2][foundOp]; //t_Op = t_PredecessorStart(from startingTimeMatrix) + t_PredecessorProcess(from predecessorTimes)
                        }
                    }

                // Mark the found operation as done
                for (int z3=0;z3<nOp;z3++){
                    if (indiProcess.get(z3).remainingPredecessors[foundOp] == 1){
                        indiProcess.get(z3).remainingPredecessors[foundOp] = 0; // FoundOp is done and is now no longer a predecessor on which other operations have to wait for
                    }
                }

                indiProcess.get(foundOp).operationDone = true;
                }
            }


            //Calculate new  Starting Operations
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){

                // Operation has no remaining Predecessor and wasnt done yet: Ready to Start
                if (max(indiProcess.get(z).remainingPredecessors)==0 && indiProcess.get(z).operationDone == false){
                    indiProcess.get(z).operationReadyToStart = true;
                    indiProcess.get(z).operationNotReady = false;
                }

                // Operation has no remaining Predecessor, but is already done
                if (max(indiProcess.get(z).remainingPredecessors)==0 && indiProcess.get(z).operationDone == true){
                    indiProcess.get(z).operationReadyToStart = false;
                    indiProcess.get(z).operationNotReady = false;
                }

                // Operation still has remaining Predecessors
                if (max(indiProcess.get(z).remainingPredecessors)!=0){
                    indiProcess.get(z).operationNotReady = true;
                    indiProcess.get(z).operationReadyToStart = false;
                    indiProcess.get(z).operationDone = false;
                }
            }


            //Abbruchbedingungen ermitteln
            operationsDone = 0;
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if(indiProcess.get(z).operationDone == true){
                    operationsDone++;
                }
            }
        }


        //Fertigungszeiten berechnen
        for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
            timesProduction[z] = max(startingTimeMatrix[z]) + indiProcess.get(z).timeWorking;
        }
    }

    void correctingAllocation (List<Operationen> operationsList){
        // Liste der Maschinen erstellen
        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++){
            indiProcess.get(i).availableMachines = new int[nMa];
            copyArr(operationsList.get(i).availableMachines,indiProcess.get(i).availableMachines);
        }


        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++){
            int requestedMachine = indiAllocation[i];
            if (indiProcess.get(i).availableMachines[requestedMachine] == 0){
                // Requested Machine cant execute the operation
                // Find available Machines
                List<Integer> numbersAvailableMachines = new ArrayList<>(); 
                for (int j=0;j<nMa;j++){
                    if (indiProcess.get(i).availableMachines[j] == 1){
                        numbersAvailableMachines.add(j);
                    }
                }
                // Pick random Machine of the available machines
                double randomMachine =  round((numbersAvailableMachines.size()-1) * randomNumber(),0);
                int newMachine = (int) randomMachine;

                //Put new Machine in Allocation
                indiAllocation[i] = numbersAvailableMachines.get(newMachine);
            }
        }
    }



    // Decodierung
    void decodierung(int[][] Vorrangmatrix, int[][] Maschinenzeiten){

        // VORBEREITUNG
        //Prozesszeitenmatrix bestimmen aus Zuordnung und Maschinenzeiten und Maschinenzeit in Matrix der Vorgänger-Prozess-Zeiten eintragen
        for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
            indiProcess.get(z).workingMachine = indiAllocation[z]; 
            indiProcess.get(z).timeWorking = Maschinenzeiten[z][indiProcess.get(z).workingMachine];
        }
    

        // z=zeile/row
        // s=spalte/column
        for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
            for (int s=0;s<nOp;s++){
                if  (Vorrangmatrix[z][s]==1){
                    predecessorWorkingTimes[z][s] = indiProcess.get(s).timeWorking;
                }
                else{
                    predecessorWorkingTimes[z][s] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        
        // Get the predecessors of every Operation and save them under Process.get(x).Predecessors
        for (int i=0;i<nOp;i++){
            copyArr(Vorrangmatrix[i],indiProcess.get(i).predecessor);
        }
    

        int[][] arrayV = copyMatrix(Vorrangmatrix);
        for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
            if (max(Vorrangmatrix[z]) < 0.1)
                arrayA[z] = 1;
            else{
                arrayA[z] = 0; 
            }
        }

        calculateStartingTimeMatrix();

        // Beginn Giffler-Thompson Algorithmus
        int gtaBreakingCondition = 0;
        while (gtaBreakingCondition < nOp){
            operationDash = 0;
            operationDashDash = 0; 
            operationStar = 0;

            // GT - Step 2.H1: Get O' (Operation with earliest Productiontime, finsihed first)
            int earliestProductiontime = 1000;
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if (arrayA[z] == 1 && timesProduction[z]< earliestProductiontime){
                     operationDash = z;
                     earliestProductiontime = timesProduction[z];
                }
            }

            // GT - Step 2.H2: Get B, all Operations of A on the same Machine as O'
            int currentMachine = indiAllocation[operationDash];

            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if (arrayA[z]==1 && indiAllocation[z]==currentMachine){
                    arrayB[z]=1;
                }
                else{
                    arrayB[z] = 0;
                }
            }
            
            // GT - Step 2.H3: Get O'' (Operation of B with ealiest starting Time)
            int earliestStartingtime = 1000;
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if (arrayB[z]==1 && max(startingTimeMatrix[z])<earliestStartingtime){
                    operationDashDash = z;
                    earliestStartingtime = max(startingTimeMatrix[z]);
                }
            }


            // GT - Step 2.H4: Delete operations outside of the sigma window
            
            //Check if earliest starttime is smaller then occupation
            int starttime;
            if (max(startingTimeMatrix[operationDashDash]) < indiMachines.get(currentMachine).timeOccupation){
                starttime = indiMachines.get(currentMachine).timeOccupation;
            }
            else{
                starttime = max(startingTimeMatrix[operationDashDash]);
            } 
            
            double sigma = 0.5;

            // Delete Operations outside
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if (arrayB[z]==1 && max(startingTimeMatrix[z]) > (starttime + sigma * (timesProduction[operationDash] - starttime))){
                    arrayB[z] = 0;
                }
            }


            //GT - Step 2.H5: Get O*
            int permutation = 1000;
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if (arrayB[z]==1 && indiSequence[z]<permutation){
                    permutation = indiSequence[z];
                    operationStar = z;
                }
            }


            // Mark OperationStern as done
            arrayA[operationStar] = -1; // OperationStar is done, mark with -1 in A
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if (arrayA[z] != -1){
                    arrayV[z][operationStar] = 0; // OperationStar is no longer predecessor of other operations
                }
            }
            arrayV[operationStar] = oneValue(arrayV[operationStar], -1); // OperationStar is done, mark with -1 in V

            // Set the starting time of operationStar
            if (max(startingTimeMatrix[operationStar]) < indiMachines.get(currentMachine).timeOccupation){
                indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeStart = indiMachines.get(currentMachine).timeOccupation;
            }
            if (max(startingTimeMatrix[operationStar]) >= indiMachines.get(currentMachine).timeOccupation){
                indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeStart = max(startingTimeMatrix[operationStar]);
            }

            // Set the ending time of operationStar
            indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeEnd = indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeStart + indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeWorking;

            // Set new occupation time of the current machine
            indiMachines.get(currentMachine).timeOccupation = indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeEnd;


            // GT - Schritt 4: Add successors of O* to A
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){

                if (max(arrayV[z]) == 0){
                    arrayA[z] = 1;
                }
                if (max(arrayV[z]) == -1){
                    arrayA[z] = -1;
                }
                if (max(arrayV[z]) == 1){
                    arrayA[z] = 0;
                }
            }

            //GT - Step 5: Update occupation time of the current machine to every operation which is also done on that machine
            for (int z=0;z<nOp;z++){
                if (arrayA[z] != -1 && indiAllocation[z] == currentMachine){
                    startingTimeMatrix[z][nOp] = indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeEnd;
                }
            }


            //Update startingTimeMatrix, because the occupation time in startingTimeMatrix[z][nOp] was updated
            calculateStartingTimeMatrix();


            //Give the working Machine some Information about the Operation: Needed for the BarChart
            indiMachines.get(currentMachine).plannedOperations = addOneToArray(indiMachines.get(currentMachine).plannedOperations, operationStar);
            indiMachines.get(currentMachine).startingTimesOps = addOneToArray(indiMachines.get(currentMachine).startingTimesOps, indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeStart);
            indiMachines.get(currentMachine).endingTimesOps = addOneToArray(indiMachines.get(currentMachine).endingTimesOps, indiProcess.get(operationStar).timeEnd);

            // Calculate Breaking Condition
            gtaBreakingCondition = count(arrayA, -1);
        }
    }


    // 1-Bit-Mutation
    void einbitmutation(int nOp, double mutProbability){
        
        for (int i = 0; i<nOp; i++) {
            double random = randomNumber();
            if (random<mutProbability){
                if (indiAllocation[i]==1){
                    indiAllocation[i]=0;
                } 
                else {
                    indiAllocation[i]=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Mixed Mutation
    void mixedmutation(int nOp, float mixMutProbability, int typeCoding){

        double random = randomNumber();
        if(random > mixMutProbability){
            int sectionStart = (int) round(randomNumber()*nOp,0);
            int sectionEnd = (int) round(randomNumber()*nOp,0);
            while (sectionEnd == sectionStart){
                sectionEnd = (int) round(randomNumber()*nOp,0);
            }
            if (sectionEnd < sectionStart){
                int temp = sectionStart;
                sectionStart = sectionEnd;
                sectionEnd = temp;
            }

            int[] tempArr = new int[sectionEnd-sectionStart];
            if (typeCoding == 0){
                tempArr = copyArraySection(indiAllocation, sectionStart, tempArr, 0, sectionEnd-sectionStart);
                List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int k=0;k<tempArr.length;k++){
                    tempList.add(tempArr[k]);
                }
                Collections.shuffle(tempList);
                int[] mixedArr = tempList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
                indiAllocation = copyArraySection(mixedArr, 0, indiAllocation, sectionStart, sectionEnd-sectionStart);
            }
            else if (typeCoding == 1){
                tempArr = copyArraySection(indiSequence, sectionStart, tempArr, 0, sectionEnd-sectionStart);
                List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int k=0;k<tempArr.length;k++){
                    tempList.add(tempArr[k]);
                }
                Collections.shuffle(tempList);
                int[] mixedArr = tempList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
                indiSequence = copyArraySection(mixedArr, 0, indiSequence, sectionStart, sectionEnd-sectionStart);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Wrong Input for Coding Type of Mixed Mutation");
            }
        }
    }

    // Swap-Mutation
    void swapmutation(int nOp, float mutProbability){

        for (int i = 0; i<nOp; i++) {
            double random = randomNumber();
            if (random<mutProbability) {
                double random2 = round(randomNumber()*(nOp-1),0);
                int randomposition = (int)random2;
                int saveNumber = indiSequence[randomposition];
                indiSequence[randomposition] = indiSequence[i];
                indiSequence[i] = saveNumber;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I would like to describe the programm even a bit more, but i already wrote a lot. You can fine the whole program with more explanations, pictures and examples here:
https://github.com/enruk/Productionplaner

I know its not allowed to link to third party website but i really hesitate to copy every class in here. I don't think this helps clarity and understanding.

Why I post it here?
My problem is that in self-taught programming, I only work up to the point where the program works. I miss a kind of mentor who tells me: Yes, this works, but it can be done better (which is i guess the point of this website).

As already mentioned, I am also happy to receive feedback on the remaining classes of the program or the entire program (but i know that this is not the purpose of this website). I know the program is quiet big to give a detailed feedback. What I look for are more general tips / advices. I appreciate the smallest advices.
What can i do better / on which topics should I work / research more?

- Structure of the program
- Basic algorithms
- Structure and use of methods
- Use of data structures

Thank you very much already!
I know there are some german comments / varaibles names. Apologies. I will fix that asap.

Also I am happy about good recommendations for online courses.
I am currently doing this one:
https://www.udemy.com/course/java-training-ullenboom/

Comment: First thing I notice is that your variable names are not always self-descriptive. Things like `nOp` or `susRank` make it hard to follow along.

Comment: Also utility methods like `randomNumber()`, `addOneToArray()` and so on should be outsourced to some sort of helper class. Right now it's hard to find out what your class is supposed to do.

Comment: What I also noticed is that most of your methods return `void`. When doing any form of calculations (and it seems you do) it's better to follow an input/output style IMHO. This makes your code a lot more testable (defined input results in expected output).

Comment: @slauth thank you so much for you feedback. Really appreciate it. My Answer is a bit late, bc i was in vacation. Now that i think about it, your third comment in particular makes sense for maintenance and troubleshooting purposes. Also first and second comment are absolutly clear. I try to change this asap

Comment: @slauth Regarding your question about the purpose of the class: Each class "Individuum" is a production schedule. The main attributes are the sequence and the allocation. Each position i in the two arrays gives operation i of the production process a number in the sequence and an allocation to a machine. In the method "decodierung" i create an admissible productions schedule from these two vectors using the giffler thompson algorithm. I hope that helps a bit.